# How to remove last character of a sentence based on specific character in javascript or jquery with regular expression

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sentence 'Welcome to a project are you a', Here I need to remove 'a' that should only remove when sentence contains last letter as 'a',else I have tried this code but its not working here

### HTML

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="messages"></ul>
```

### script

```
var text = 'Welcome to project, are you a (1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident)';
    var regex = /\((.*)\)/;
    var m;
    m = regex.exec(text);
        console.log(m[1]);
        // 1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident
        var list = m[1];

        var items = list.split(/([\d]. )/g);

        var message = $('.messages');

    var introText = text.split('(');
    var test = introText[0]
    alert(test.replace(/\a$/, ""));
```

Comment: its not working here,still not able to remove a

Comment: Please try it: 'Welcome to project, are you a (1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident)'.replace(' a ',' ');

Comment: That text will be coming from ajax call in my project so  sentence  may come different  some times,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following script below:

```js
var text = 'Welcome to project, are you a (1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident)';
    var regex = /\((.*)\)/;
    var m;
    m = regex.exec(text);
        console.log(m[1]);
        // 1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident
        var list = m[1];

        var items = list.split(/([\d]. )/g);

        var message = $('.messages');

    var introText = text.split('(');
    var test = introText[0].trim();
    //alert(test.replace(/\a$/, ""));
    if(test.slice(-2) == " a"){
     alert(test.slice(0,-1)); 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="messages"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help when I change the text into var text = 'how do you want to claim (1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident)' again alert is not coming...that text will be changing in my project always.